# Developing Vuejs/Laravel Application. Which one is better for material design? mdbootstrap or Vuetify?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, mdbootstrap, bootstrap-material-design

I am developing Laravel/Vuejs Web Application using Bootstrap. There are some components which requires material design. I am confused in selecting between Vuetify and MDBootstrap (though its paid).

can anyone please recommend what should i use and why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MDBootstrap, but I've used Vuetify in my previous project, and I would recommend it for it's size-able user base and a concise documentation. It just works.

Comment: Thank you @Murwa. Can i use Bootstrap with Vuetify? Is it a good option?

Comment: No, you don't have to... You can just do fine with Vuetify alone. However, there is no harm in using both, if you feel comfortable with bootstrap.